# Rebasing to upstream version

Tags: git, algorithm, rebase

Imagine I have such a git config:

```
o--o--o--o--o--o remote master
       \
        o--o--o--o my master
            \
             o--o--o feature branch
```

And for example I want to rebase my master branch on remote master to get upstream changes. I could do this like this:

```
get rebase --onto remote_maste remote_maste my_master
```

Then I will get this structure:

```
o--o--o--o--o--o remote master o--o--o--o my master
       \                       A' B'
        o--o
        A  B\
             o--o--o feature branch
```

Then I'm force-pushing it to my repo to make my_master updates available to others(imagine that the my_master branch was closed for new commits during the rebasing process):

```
git push -f origin my_master:my_mater
```

So I have two questions.
The first is: will others be able to rebase their feature branches to updated master?(I think yes but I'm not sure)
And the second which is the main one: if the previous question's answer is yes then what's going to be with these A and B commits since they  are already in updated master(but with other hashes)? Will they disappear, be applied above(so I will have duplicate commits) or what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should figure out that they are the same and not apply them again.

Try this:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase origin/master -i #or just master
```

you will see a list of commits to be appled, it will have figured out that A and B have already been applied, and left them out, as long as they are identical.

If they are slightly different, (like if somebody amended one in a feature branch) it should leave them in for the rebase, and try to apply them again, and either succeed with a '3-way merge', or ask you to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Thanks. If so it's geat for me.